# How do I add a data feed to Tellor's Oracle?

Tags: oracles, tellor

I need a data type that it doesn't seem they currently have a feed for.  I couldn't find anything in the docs.  Anyone successfully done this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Make a pull request to add your query to [the catalog](https://github.com/tellor-io/dataSpecs). You may have to make a new query type if it's something special. Then go tip your query in the Tellor contract.